# Override div style link color in css

Tags: html, css

I'm placing a button (created by a css) in my html page.
Currently this button inherits the link color from the div.

I'm trying to override these link colors and make the button show a link in a different color.

I have created a button style in the css file like this, and I was pretty sure by specifying the link colors in the button, I would automatically override the div link colors.

```
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 14px;
  margin: 8px 0 0;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #fff;
  background: #49b1fb;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #5196d5), color-stop(1, #49b1fb));
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #5196d5, #49b1fb);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #5196d5 0%, #49b1fb 100%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4c8cc8;
  link {text-decoration: none; color: #FFF;}
  visited {text-decoration: none; color: #FFF;}
  hover {text-decoration: none; color: #FFF;}
  active {text-decoration: none; color: #FFF;}
}
```

I use the button like this:

```
<div id="widecontent">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-inner">
            <div class="column_left">
                <h2>Download</h2>Click below to download the app:
                <br/>
                <a href="setup.exe" title="Download" class="button">Download</a>
            </div>
```

However, the link color of the button is the same as the div style. 
The link colors as I have defined them in the css file don't show an effect.

What is the correct way to override the link color of the div / what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: `hover{ }`  is not a thing. It's: `.button:hover { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define it like this for hover for example:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 14px;
  margin: 8px 0 0;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #fff;
  background: #49b1fb;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #5196d5), color-stop(1, #49b1fb));
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #5196d5, #49b1fb);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #5196d5 0%, #49b1fb 100%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4c8cc8;
}

.button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: I did NOT downvote it. And for me it works. Perhaps the downvoter could comment on his downvote.

Comment: @tmighty no problem, it's important that it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

you are confusing properties with pseudo-classes (`:active`/`:hover` and etc)

so you should use them outside of the rule, and not inside.

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 14px;
  margin: 8px 0 0;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #fff;
  background: #49b1fb;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #5196d5), color-stop(1, #49b1fb));
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #5196d5, #49b1fb);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #5196d5 0%, #49b1fb 100%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4c8cc8;
}


.button:visited {
  color: green
}

.button:focus {
  color: purple
}

.button:hover {
  color: red
}

.button:active {
  color: yellow
}
```

```html
I use the button like this:

<div id="widecontent">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="content-inner">
      <div class="column_left">
        <h2>Download</h2>Click below to download the app:
        <br/>
        <a href="setup.exe" title="Download" class="button">Download</a>
      </div>
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you very much. I need to accept @jakob 's answer because he was faster, but your's is of course just excellently written and beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: Go ahead and accept whatever you prefer, but just a tip, don't accept just because it was the fastest. Accept because it  was the most helpful for you

Comment: I understand. For me, it was Jakob's. It was straight to the point where I went wrong. Perhaps other people profit more from your reply. Oh, these decisions... :-)